# Get FieldDescription for protected field in one of the superclasses

Tags: byte-buddy

Based on a TypeDefinition (eg. the instrumented type) I want to quickly find the FieldDescription for a protected variable. I know the variable is there in one of the superclasses but I don't know exactly in which one. Here's a simplified example:

```java
class C1 { protected int id; }

class C2 extends C1 {}
```

Based on the typeDefinitionC1 = TypeDescription.ForLoadedType.of(C1.class), I can find the field by doing something like this:

```java
typeDefinitionC1.getDeclaredFields().filter(named("id")).getOnly()
```

But using the type definition for C2 it doesn't work because the field is not declared in C2. I've written a small function to iterate over all superclasses in order to find the field but I would expect ByteBuddy to let me do something like:

```java
typeDefinitionC2.getFields().filter(named("id").and(isProtected())).getOnly()
```

Is there some convenient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new FieldLocator.ForExactType(typeDefinitionC1).locate(named("id"))`.

Byte Buddy does not bake the location into the description API as the reflection API does as location is often dependant on the lookup site and use case.

Comment: The suggested solution didn't solve the problem but did help me find the solution I was looking for: `new FieldLocator.ForClassHierarchy(C2.asErasure()).locate("id").getField()`